# Spring MVC jsp tag place holders for tag value

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am not sure as how to define the value attribute in the Spring MVC form tags. I am querying the database and i would like to return data to the jsp. I am returning an object to the view in the form of a list. I would like to know how to write the attribute value for both an option list and a input box. Under is my code:

**jsp**

```
<form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="POST" commandName="citizens" action="citizen_registration.htm">

<li>
<label>Select Gender</label><form:select path="genderId" id="genderId" title="Select Your Gender"><form:options items = "${gender.genderList}" selected=???? itemValue="genderId" itemLabel="genderDesc" />
</form:select><form:errors path="genderId" class="errors"/>
</li>               
                                            <li><form:label for="weight" path="weight">Enter Weight <i>(lbs)</i></form:label>
<form:input path="weight" id="weight" title="Enter Weight" value= ???/><form:errors path="weight" class="errors"/>
</li>
```

**JavaDao**

The function returns:
........................

```
   List<Citizens> listOfCitizens = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new CitizensMapper());      
    return listOfCitizens;
```

**Controller**

```
if (user_request.equals("Query")){
 logger.debug("about to preform query");
 citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen);

 if(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen).isEmpty()){
    model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close");
    model.addAttribute("results","Notice: Query Caused No Records To Be Retrived!");    
  }

//how do i return the List<Citizens> listOfCitizens
//or what should be done to send the user the data from the database
return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");                    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value comes from the model object (`citizens` in your case) defined by your form's `commandName` attribute. Spring uses that and the `path` attribute to lookup the value of the form objects.

So, there is no need to specifically provide a value for the `value` attribute, for instance.

**EDIT:**

Here's a simplified example:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/editCitizen", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String editCitizen(@ModelAttribute("citizen") Citizen citizen, Model model) {
    // set attributes of citizen
    citizen.genderId = "M";
    citizen.weight = 180;
    // etc.

    // set other model attributes like lists for <form:select>s
    model.addAttribute("genderList", <list of genders>);
    return "path.to.my.jsp";
  }

<form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="POST" commandName="citizen" action="citizen_registration.htm">
  <form:select path="genderId" items="${genderList}" itemLabel="genderDesc" itemValue="genderId"></form:select>
  <form:input path="weight" id="weight" title="Enter Weight"/>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Why doesn't my return listOfCitizens not return the values into the attributes. The function is defined as follows public List<Citizens> getListOfCitizens(Citizens citizen){......gets data from database.....return listOfCitizens;}

Comment: I did a check from the database and the list is not NULL it has data, one record

Comment: It's up to your controller method to provide the model for the JSP. Does yours do that?

Comment: Also, it's likely that a `List` is not an appropriate value for your form's backing object (`citizens`), as it appears that your form is setup to edit a _single_ citizen.

Comment: Ok i think i am getting a clearer picture now but i am still abit confused. I understand when you say the controller needs to provide a model for the view e.g. model.addAttribute(.....). However this is an object model.addAttribute would not work.

Yes it is a list however what do you mean by a List is not appropriate for the form's backing object(citizens). I know citizen is a single object however if you return a list to the view should it not show the first item in the list until the user loops through the list showing one row at a time.

Comment: No, Spring does not automatically see a `List` and provide "looping" functionality for the user. Your backing object needs to match what the JSP is looking for. I'll try to provide an example soon.

Comment: I updated the question with the controller code. Please do guide me to the proper way to do this.

Comment: I must also ask if i query the database and the query returns several rows how do i handle that? Do i need to restrict the query to always return one row at a time and when the user needs the next row i get it from the database? Please tell me how this is handled. Also if that isn't the correct approach do i need to make the CommandName object an array?

Comment: So i returned the following model.addAllAttributes(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));
return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration"); and this worked it returned the record, however i am wondering how it would work if the resultset contain multiple records and how can i navigate through them.

Comment: I recommend you take the approach from my example. Provide a single record to the JSP, not a list. Your controller should retrieve a single record, not a list. If you want to provide buttons to the user to "save and get the next record", you can do so. It could be done with post-redirect-get or via AJAX calls. That's beyond the scope of this question, though.